# Problems with Ionic Emulate IOS! How do I emulate ios?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

This is the error I get when typing ionic emulate ios.

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/root/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/6CA00327-FD21-4746-97B0-5515640534B9/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/amirmeshkin/ionic/todo/platforms/ios/build/emulator/todo.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/amirmeshkin/ionic/todo/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/amirmeshkin/ionic/todo/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/amirmeshkin/ionic/todo/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Comment: check whether the ios platform added in your or not by typing the cmd as `ionic platform ls`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue it is permission issue to the folder where you are creating the project ...make the user as  owner of the directory/folder using CHOWN.... and then try again